# sbt needs several recompiles / finds allways more changes

Tags: scala, caching, build, compilation, sbt

I have some problems with sbt since quite some time. It needs several compilation runs to catch up with changes and it finds everytime something new to compile until everything is done. It does not correctly identify all dependencies to be recompiled in one go as it does usually.

I'm trying to figure out since when, but it happens I think since I upgrade vom 13.6 to 13.9. Although if I revert now, I can still reproduce it.

The problem persist even when I do a clean project checkout and clean everything. Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Here is a example output, between calls to test:compile nothing changed of course in the source files.

Any idea how to debug or even fix this?

```
> test:compile
[info] Compiling 31 Scala sources to <project>\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Packaging <project>\target\scala-2.11\frontend-core_2.11-1.8.42-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 18 s, completed 25.09.2015 18:59:45
> test:compile
[info] Compiling 10 Scala sources to <project>\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[warn] <project>\src\main\scala\com\cupenya\frontend\service\EngineDataService.scala:959: match may not be exhaustive.
[info] Packaging <project>\target\scala-2.11\frontend-core_2.11-1.8.42-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed 25.09.2015 19:00:02
> test:compile
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to <project>\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Packaging <project>\target\scala-2.11\frontend-core_2.11-1.8.42-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 10 s, completed 25.09.2015 19:00:28
> test:compile
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources to D:\jpx\IdeaProjects\cupenya-root\frontend-core\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Packaging D:\jpx\IdeaProjects\cupenya-root\frontend-core\target\scala-2.11\frontend-core_2.11-1.8.42-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed 25.09.2015 19:01:31
>
```

Comment: And it also does not always detect all changes, resulting in NoSuchMethod errors, so I manually have to clean. I#m trying to reproduce this in a simpler case, but seems to be related to the complexity of the project maybe.

Comment: We observe this now also on other nodes, so it is not OS dependent but seems to be an issue / point of the project.